# Clarification in appendix 3 of Ulrich Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, exponential-function

I am reading Complex Analysis by David C. Ulrich. In appendix 3 titled "Sin, Cos and Exp", Ulrich defines $\exp , \sin , \cos$ by using the power series. After a few lines, he writes that

> The absolute convergence of the series shows that the terms can be
> rearranged as desired, and it follows that \begin{align} \exp (iz) =
> \cos (z) + i \sin (z) \end{align}

But it looks to me that rearrangement is not really necessary from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614181/showing-that-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-sum-n-1-infty-a-2n-sum-n-1) which I asked on this site. Although it is not necessary, how can it be done? I have tried a lot but I do not see it. Hints are appreciated!

Comment: Compute the first several terms for exp(ix), simplify them. Some will be real, others complex; separate them like this

Comment: @DavidRaveh I am looking for a way to make sense of the author's justification.

Comment: Are you asking how the series being absolutely convergent allows him to rearrange the sequence? Sorry, it's a little unclear

Comment: I would say: compare with $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}n\stackrel?=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{2n+1}$. But the reality is that I won't be reading the book so chances are I will never know what rearrangements the author is referring to.

Comment: @meth- Just begin with $\exp(x)$ and make the substitution $x \rightarrow iz$. Now simply reduce the $i^n$ terms in the series, then group the real and imaginary parts together. That's how Euler did it.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio The author does not make it clear though.

Comment: @CyclotomicField That seems like one way to think about it.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are convergent then $\sum(a_n\pm  b_n)$ are convergent and $\sum(a_n\pm b_n)=\sum a_n\pm \sum b_n.$ Apply this to $a_n={(iz)^n\over n!}$ and $b_n={(-iz)^n\over n!}.$ Then $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2\cos z$ and $e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2i\sin z.$ From these two equations we get the formula $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z.$

Comment: I guess the author just means by absolute convergent of the power series of $e^{iz}$, we can collect the terms corresponding to $\sin(z)$ and $cos(z)$ respectively to get the result. But now the author choose to use linearity instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. There is no "rearrangement" used here, it's just linearity of $\Sigma_0^\infty$.

Thanks for asking - I've been locked out, hadn't been checking every day, didn't realize I was back. yippee...

Comment: Also, there are other instances where you write "rearrangement" in the textbook, so what do you exactly mean by rearrangements?